# jQuery isn't working properly on my Angular.js site

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm trying to get Masonry.js to work on my site, and while I have succeeded in that, it is a super hacky solution and I have no idea why it works (and it doesn't work well).

My main two issues are:
    jQuery isn't working properly
    It only works with a setTimeout (otherwise elements stack on eachother since the images have no height until loaded)

Here is my code: (or view on [github](https://github.com/JordanBourne/Collage) )

masonryStyle.js (this file is really weird. The jQuery only works if that exact function is there. Remove any piece and it breaks)

```
setTimeout(function() {
var elem = document.querySelector('.grid');
var msnry = new Masonry( elem, {
    itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
}, 500);

$('.grid').masonry({
columnWidth: '.grid-sizer',
itemSelector: '.grid-item',
percentPosition: true
});
```

home.html (content that needs to be masonry

```
<div class = "searchBar">
<form ng-submit = "searchAuthor()" class = "searchSection">
    <input type = "text" class = "searchInput" ng-model = "byAuthor" placeholder = "Search Authors">
    <input type = "submit" class = "searchSubmit" value = "Search">
</form>
<div class = "spacer"></div>
<form ng-submit = "searchTag()" class = "searchSection">
    <input type = "text" class = "searchInput" ng-model = "byTag" placeholder = "Search Tags">
    <input type = "submit" class = "searchSubmit" value = "Search">
</form>
</div>

<div class = "grid">
<div class = "grid-item" ng-repeat = "image in images">
    <img ng-src = "{{image.link}}" class = "image">
    <div class = "imageTitle">{{image.title}}</div>
    <div class = "imageAuthor">Posted by: {{image.author}}</div>
    <div class = "imageUpvote"><a href ng-click = "upvote(image)"><i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></a> {{image.upvotes}}</div>
    <div class = "imageTags" ng-repeat = "tag in image.tags">{{tag}}&nbsp;     </div>
</div>
</div>
```

index.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pin Viewer</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Quicksand:400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
</head>
<body ng-app = "app" ng-controller = "MainCtrl">
    <div class = "pageWrapper">
        <div class = "mainPage">
            <div class = "navBar">
                <a href = "#/profile"><div class = "appName">{{user.username}}</div></a>
                <a href = "/login/twitter/"><div class = "navButton" ng-hide = "user.username">Log In</div></a>
                <a href ng-click = "logout()"><div class = "navButton" ng-show = "user.username">Log Out</div></a>
            </div>

            <div class = "pageTitle"><a href = "#/">Pin Viewer</a></div>

            <div class = "postImage">
                <button class = "postImageButton" ng-click = "postImage()">Post Image</button>
            </div>
            <div class = "error">{{error}}</div>
        </div>

        <div class = "pageContent">

        <ui-view></ui-view>

        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="javascripts/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
    <script src='javascripts/masonry.pkgd.js'></script>
    <script src='javascripts/angular.min.js'></script>
    <script src='javascripts/angular-ui-router.js'></script>
    <script src="javascripts/angularApp.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this angularised version of masonary: https://github.com/passy/angular-masonry
Some jQuery origins make a problem in Angular.js app, otherwise if you are going with jQuery you have to load all the jQuery functions on each route change

For example:

```
$rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
      $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
  });`
```

You have to do like the above.